# Using Templates to set function types in a class gives error

Tags: c++, function, templates

So I have this class:

```
 template <typename callBackOne,
           typename callBackTwo>
class MyClass {       // The class
  public: 
    callBackOne cbo;
    callBackTwo cbt;           
    MyClass(callBackOne cbop, callBackTwo cbtp){
      cbop();
      cbtp();
    }
};
```

All it does is call the functions you give in the parameter for its constructor.
The callback function types are deduced by a template. I cannot do this any other way.
Why does it error when I try:

```
MyClass<void,void> test(voidFuncOne,voidFuncTwo);
```

The error:

```
error: invalid parameter type ‘void’
no matching function for call to ‘MyClass<void, void>::MyClass(int (&)(), void (&)())’
```

24 |   MyClass<void,void> testy(test,testTwo);

Ive tried lots of different things including:

```
MyClass<void(&)(),void(&)()> test(test,testTwo);
MyClass<void,void> test(&test,&testTwo);
MyClass<void (*)(void),void (*)(void)> test(test,testTwo);
```

I know its possible to pass in functions as parameters like this but i just cant figure out how. Its a problem of knowledge of the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **problem** is that the explicit template arguments that you're passing are of type `void` but the function arguments `voidFuncOne` and `voidFuncTwo` will be implicitly converted to `void (*)()` and passed but since there is no conversion from a `void(*)()` to `void` you get the mentioned error.

##### C++17

With C++17, you can make use of [**class template argument deduction**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)(aka CTAD) as shown below:

```
template <typename callBackOne,
           typename callBackTwo>
class MyClass {       // The class
  public: 
    callBackOne cbo;
    callBackTwo cbt;           
    MyClass(callBackOne cbop, callBackTwo cbtp){
      cbop();
      cbtp();
    }
};
void voidFuncOne()
{
    std::cout<<"funcone called"<<std::endl;
}
void voidFuncTwo()
{
    std::cout<<"functow called"<<std::endl;
}
MyClass test(voidFuncOne,voidFuncTwo); //CTAD used automatically here
//-----^------------------------------->no need to pass arguments explicitly since CTAD will be used
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/59sjes2Pb)

##### Pre-C++17

Here you can explicitly specify the template arguments to be of type `void(*)()` as shown below:

```
template <typename callBackOne,
           typename callBackTwo>
class MyClass {       // The class
  public: 
    callBackOne cbo;
    callBackTwo cbt;           
    MyClass(callBackOne cbop, callBackTwo cbtp){
      cbop();
      cbtp();
    }
};
void voidFuncOne()
{
    std::cout<<"funcone called"<<std::endl;
}
void voidFuncTwo()
{
    std::cout<<"functow called"<<std::endl;
}

//------vvvvvvvvv--vvvvvvvvv--------------------------------->template arguments changed from void to void(*)()
MyClass<void(*)(), void(*)()> test(voidFuncOne,voidFuncTwo);
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/hy8I7tGv1)

Answer (score 2):

Class member `cbo` and `cbt` seems useless: they are not assigned in `MyClass`'s constructor and are not used at all.

If you want to save function pointers for later use, you can try `std::function` in `<functional>`. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename callBackOne,  typename callBackTwo>
class MyClass {       // The class
public:
    std::function<callBackOne> cbo;
    std::function<callBackTwo> cbt;

    MyClass(callBackOne cbop, callBackTwo cbtp) : cbo(cbop), cbt(cbtp) {
    }
};

void voidFuncOne() { std::cout << "One\n"; }
void voidFuncTwo() { std::cout << "Two\n"; }

int main()
{
    MyClass<void(), void()> test(voidFuncOne, voidFuncTwo);
    test.cbo();
    test.cbt();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::function` is a pretty heavy beast – if you are just dealing with function pointers nothing speaks against using them directly. Correct, though, is need for using the initialiser list...

Comment: @Aconcagua you're right, using `MyClass<void(*)(), void(*)()>` without changing `MyClass`'s definition is better.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter type of the template class is `void`, but the parameter type of the constructor is not the `void` type, which is the root cause of the error.

try the following:

`MyClass<int(), void()> test(voidFuncOne,voidFuncTwo);`

or

`MyClass<decltype(voidFuncOne),decltype(voidFuncTwo)> test(voidFuncOne,voidFuncTwo);`

Comment: With [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) you even could simply have `MyClass test(voidFuncOne, voidFuncTwo)` – relying on C++ 17, though.

Comment: Yes, this is a very good implementation (since C++17)